# How can i use echarts (treemap) to include onClick listeners?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, echarts

I want to use an onClick listener on the lowest level of my treemap so that when a node is clicked (without any children), information pertaining to that node is displayed in a Antd drawer/card component. I know the docs have an nodeClick in the series-treemap API, but it cant function as an onClick listener - it only takes string or bool. How can this be accomplished

https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.nodeClick

Answer (score 0):

Use Echarts [mouse events](https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/concepts/event/#event-and-action) :

```js
myChart.on('click', function(params) {
  //Check if what you clicked on is part of a treemap
  if(params.seriesType == "treemap"){
    console.log(params); //full node object
  }
});
```

Every piece of information about the node is inside `params`. For example, you can get its name with `params.name` or a list of its parents with `params.treeAncestors`. You can then save these information an display them anywhere you want.

Comment: what if this is in react? i am not rendering using the mychart and DOM 
  return <ReactECharts option={treeMapOption} style={{ height: '750px' }} />;

Comment: I didn't know you can't have access to an echarts instance in react, I can't help you with that issue then, sorry.